# Is an institution or a supervisor necessary to make a submission?

Tags: publications, conference

I am a motivated student and I had a well running project with a nice exposé presentation at a conference. I could do some more work on this and publish further papers, but eventually I would like to do this on my own after my studies as side project in my free time. Is it generally possible to make submissions to scientific conferences without a scientific supervisor or/and without a scientific institution?

If you know please tell if it depends on the conference or the research area.

Thoughts about if doing this makes sense to you can be placed here, too.

The research field is related to computer science, human computer interaction and music.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my area (CS), submitting a paper with no scientific affiliation is possible and happens quite regularly.
Many conferences nowadays use double-blind review, were names and affiliation of the authors are not known to the reviewers, so it should matter even less if you do not have the "right" affiliation.